# PHP file not found after moving it

Tags: php

I have a script that moves the file and then tries to get the file to generate a thumbnail. However, it always says that the file doesn't exist. If I try `file_exists()` on the file after script execution, it seems to find it.

Pieces of my code:

```
// Move file, returns a path e.g. "\home\sambam\public_html\sa\storage\files\0\rxugn7OXoHNRY4J.mp4"
// This also sets file permissions to 0755
$source = $fs->move_from_tmp($filename);

// clear cache
clearstatcache(true);

// Now file_exists returns false
if(file_exists($source)){
  // generate thumbnail;
}
```

Move_from_tmp:

```
public function move_from_tmp($filename){
  // $this->tmp_folder = /home/sambam/public_html/ss/storage/tmp
  // this->folder =  /home/sambam/public_html/ss/storage/files/0

  if(!is_readable($this->tmp_folder.self::DS.$filename)){ chmod($this->tmp_folder.self::DS.$filename, 0755); }
  $ext = strtolower(pathinfo(basename($filename), PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  $new_filename = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);


  // Move file
  if(rename($this->tmp_folder.self::DS.$filename, $this->folder.self::DS.$new_filename.".".$ext)){
    return $this->folder.self::DS.$new_filename.".".$ext;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

This works on my local machine which is Windows but doesn't seem to work on my production machine which is Linux CentOs.

What I have also tried:

- Checked if the path has any leading/prefixed space
- File permissions
- The file is readable/writable
- And if the file exists which it does

Comment: Are you sure that the path returned from the move function is right?! Copy it and try to access it on terminal (`ls /the/path/it/returned.mp4`)

Comment: Yes and have confirmed it

Comment: Where is `move_from_tmp` from - is it your own code or a library?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have added move_from_tmp method

Comment: @EliasSoares after executing this code, when I try `file_exists("\path\to\file.mp4")` it returns true

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I tried `print_r($source)` and it prints the correct path. To test I copied this path and then assigned it to an static variable lets say $foo, then I run `file_exists($foo)` and it seems to find it

Comment: Does either folder path contain a trailing slash?  Because in your code comments they don't, and if not this can't work.

Comment: Does `$this->tmp_folder.self::DS.$filename` exist when you check from inside your function?

Comment: Does `$this->folder` exist?

Comment: @billynoah Yea it certainly does.. I can read any file in the same directory just not the one that was uploaded in the executing script